# Can kitty litter cause adverse health effects in humans?

Tags: zoology, public-health

Is there any danger to humans from co-habitating with a housecat that poops in a litterbox, and occasionally cleaning out that litterbox? Assuming you use litter you can find at the pet store, and have a cat without extraordinary circumstances, like rabies.

See for example http://www.naturalnews.com/041255_kitty_litter_bentonite_clay_harmful_ingredients.html:

> The most common cat litters contain ingredients proven to be harmful when exposed to humans and animals. The use of sodium bentonite clay and silica gel in litters coupled with the threat of alfatoxins in grain based cat litters calls for discretion when purchasing this common household item.

If there are health dangers, what steps can be taken to avoid health risks?

Comment: The cat poop itself may be a greater danger: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxoplasmosis. But "any danger" is a very low threshold: pretty much everything carries some risk to human health. You might spill some on the floor, slip on it, and break your neck.

Comment: "...use a non-clumping, non-toxic litter...".  Okay, I have to know, what brand puts "New, improved!  More toxic formula kills cats faster!" on the package?

Comment: Seconding on the cat poop answer, however, toxoplasmosis is not a serious health risk to people who are not immunocompromised or pregnant. If you are pregnant, it can cause miscarriage, if you are immunocompromised (for example, due to AIDS) it can cause a variety of symptoms, some of which are profound.